# Is there a way to push an html div in a dynamic array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to push a div in an array in `JavaScript` using template literals, let me give you an example.

```
var myArray = [];

myArray.push(<div class="example">This is an example</div>);
```

and then I can access the div in the array and display its content. But the statements after this line in my `JavaScript` acts weird. which make me wonder if I am doing the right thing. Is anything wrong with the way I am pushing my `div` into the `array`?

Comment: add quotes `myArray.push('<div class="example">This is an example</div>'); `

Comment: Notice, that in JS even `\`<div class="example">This is an example</div>\`` is a plain string, it is not a HTMLDivElement.

Comment: Thank you @Teemu-callmewhateveryouwant the quotes works perfectly for this case. But what if I want to evaluate an expression inside my div?

Comment: let's say: myArray= [];

Comment: myArray.push('<div class="Example">(2*3)</div>') I dont think this will work with single quotes. that's why I was using template literals. myArray.push(`<div class="example">${2*3}</div>`); will give you 6 when you access the array element

Comment: The string template is what you can use. Please define "_the statements after this line in my JavaScript acts weird_". Please don't tell me that you're testing with Internet Explorer ...

Comment: it works with Internet explorer, I am using notepad ++ as my text editor, after I type myArray.push(`<div class="example">${2*3}</div>`) in my script tag; every statement after it becomes bold. Even if I comment something out it doesn't show me in the text editor that is commented out( meaning the color of the commented section doesn't turn green). But when I run the code the output doesn't show the  commented parts. So why is my text editor acting this way after typing myArray.push(`<div class="example">${2*3}</div>`) , am I missing something?

Comment: Ah, this was an XY-problem as I thought it could be ... I occasionally use Notepad++, but I've no clue what is causing your issue. Considering this question has already a ton of answers, I'd suggest you to ask a new question. This time introduce your real problem with Notepad++. It's OK to ask about the tools specifically used in programming.

Comment: Ok no problem,  syntax wise I am not missing anything right? I am curious what tool do you usually use. Thanks

Comment: I might try it in that tool to see if it is only notepad++

Comment: The syntax of the template literal should be OK as it is. A bit off-topic, but I mainly use Visual Studio Code for web developement (and Notepad++ as an assistant), and Visual Studio for WPF apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the single quote in the argument:

```
myArray.push('<div class="example">This is an example</div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing quotes, you have to use it as a string:

```
var myArray = [];

myArray.push('<div class="example">This is an example</div>');
```

and then push it in some DOM element in order to show it

Answer (score 0):

```
myArray.push(`<div class="example">This is an example</div>`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use ES6 template literals for inserting a variable or making it dynamic

```
    let array=[];
    let variable="This is a example";
    array.push(`<div>${variable}</div>`)
```